# Single index+Match works, but in if statement

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

```
=IF(
A4=INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B, MATCH(A4, Sheet1!$C:$C, 0)), 
INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B, MATCH(A4, Sheet1!$C:$C,0)),

    IF(A4=INDEX(Source1!$A:$A, MATCH(A4, Source1!$B:$B, 0)), 
    INDEX(Source1!$A:$A, MATCH(A4, Source1!$B:$B, 0)),

        IF(A4=INDEX(Source2!$A:$A, MATCH(A4, Source2!$B:$B, 0)), 
        INDEX(Source2!$A:$A, MATCH(A4, Source2!$B:$B, 0)),

            IF(A4=INDEX(Source3!$A:$A, MATCH(A4, Source3!$B:$B, 0)), 
            INDEX(Source3!$A:$A, MATCH(A4, Source3!$B:$B, 0)))
)))
```

Hello everyone! Here, there are 4 different spreadsheets and I try to search value in Cell A4 to look for all 4 source spreadsheets to return right values.

When I try this, it works good as gold:

```
INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B, MATCH(A4, Sheet1!$C:$C,0))
```

But this doesn't work with simple if statement like below, as well as the nest if statements. And have no idea where I did wrong.

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B, MATCH(A4, Sheet1!$C:$C, 0))=A4,
    INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B, MATCH(A4, Sheet1!$C:$C, 0)),
    "NO")
```

With this every cell returns "NO", which is a false value. Could you take a look at it and let me know what I did wrong? Your attention and time much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if A4 is not found it will return an error and you cannot equate with an error without creating its own error.

Use this instead:

```
=IF(
ISNUMBER(MATCH(A4, Sheet1!$C:$C, 0)), 
INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B, MATCH(A4, Sheet1!$C:$C,0)),

    IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A4, Source1!$B:$B, 0)), 
    INDEX(Source1!$A:$A, MATCH(A4, Source1!$B:$B, 0)),

        IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A4, Source2!$B:$B, 0)), 
        INDEX(Source2!$A:$A, MATCH(A4, Source2!$B:$B, 0)),

            IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A4, Source3!$B:$B, 0)), 
            INDEX(Source3!$A:$A, MATCH(A4, Source3!$B:$B, 0)))
)))
```